# Symfony2 Querybuilder select

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I've 3 entities, User, Specialist, Citation.

Specialist.php

```
/**
 * 
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Citation", mappedBy="specialist")
 */
protected $citation;
```

User.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Citation", mappedBy="user", cascade={"remove"})
 */
protected $citation;
```

Citation.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Specialist", inversedBy="citation")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="specialist_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $specialist;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="citation")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $user;
```

In my database I have these registries:

Specialist table:

```
+----------+----------------+
| id       | name           |
+----------+----------------+
| 1        | Specialist One |
| 2        | Specialist Two |
+----------+----------------+
```

User table:

```
+----------+----------+
| id       | name     |
+----------+----------+
| 1        | User One |
+----------+----------+
```

Citation table:

```
+----------+--------------+---------------+---------+
| id       | name         | specialist_id | user_id |
+----------+--------------+---------------+---------+
| 1        | Citation One | 1             | 1       |
+----------+--------------+---------------+---------+
```

**I need to get all the Specialist that haven't Citations with User 1.**

If I try with this one, **SpecialistRepository.php**:

```
public function findSpecialistCitationWithUser($user) {

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->leftJoin('s.citation', 'c')
        ->where('c.user = :user')->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->getQuery()
    ;

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

[See it working at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2d18/2)
Return the Specilist which User has Citation.

I'm trying without success with this Querybuilder, **SpecialistRepository.php**:

```
public function findSpecialistNoCitationWithUser($user) {

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->leftJoin('s.citation', 'c')
        ->where('c.user <> :user')->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->getQuery()
    ;

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

[See it working at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2d18/1)
Return **no results, empty**.

Comment: This can be done with `SELECT * FROM Specialist c0_ WHERE c0_.id NOT IN (SELECT c1_.specialist_id FROM Citation c1_ WHERE c1_.user_id = 1)`.  Unfortunately, Doctrine does not accommodate subqueries.  There are work-arounds for this, though.

Comment: IMO the emtpy result is correct. You don't have such specialist. All specialists you have in your database have citation with user 1. If you add a row `2 | Citation Two | 2 | 2` to your citation table you will get specialist 2 in your result set.

Comment: Thanks a lot @geoB your query it's OK, I'll update with right code. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2d18/5

Answer (score 0):

with @geoB help, this is the answer:

```php
public function findSpecialistNoCitationWithUser($user) {

    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
    $rsm->addEntityResult('AppBundle:Specialist', 's');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('s', 'id', 'id');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('s', 'name', 'name');

    $query = $em->createNativeQuery('SELECT *
        FROM specialist c0_ 
        WHERE c0_.id NOT IN (
          SELECT c1_.specialist_id 
          FROM citation c1_
          WHERE c1_.user_id = 1
        ');

    $specialist = $query->execute();

    return $specialist;

}
```